# Using OAuth2.0 in Web Activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: rest, postman, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to connect the web activity in Azure Data Factory via OAuth 2.0 authentication?  I can do it fine in Postman [image]

but I can't seem to find the same settings in Azure [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select Web Activity

Now Click on Web Activity and then click on Settings.

[image]

Here you can select Method and also provide Headers.

[image]

For more information please refer this [blog](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/azure-data-factory-retrieve-token-from-azure-ad-using-oauth-2-0-9a3ed3f55013) by [Balamurugan Balakreshnan](https://balabala76.medium.com/)